# Type mismatch with previous external decl when use extern "C"

Tags: c++, linux

I have been reading a book about compiler and linker.The book give a demo about use the extern "C" to test the name mangling:

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace myname{
    int var = 42;
}

extern "C" double _ZN6myname3varE;

int main(){
    printf("%d\n", _ZN6myname3varE);
    return 0;
}
```

The book tells that it will print 42 but I gets an error when compile it.
Ｉ　use:

```
g++ test_extern_c.cpp -o test_extern_c
```

and get:

```
test_extern_c.cpp:15:19: error: type mismatch with previous external decl of ‘double _ZN6myname3varE’ [-fpermissive]
 extern "C" double _ZN6myname3varE;
                   ^
test_extern_c.cpp:12:9: note: previous external decl of ‘int myname::var’
     int var = 42;
         ^
test_extern_c.cpp:15:19: error: redeclaration of ‘double _ZN6myname3varE’
 extern "C" double _ZN6myname3varE;
                   ^
test_extern_c.cpp:12:9: note: previous declaration ‘int myname::var’
     int var = 42;
```

So i wonder what happen.And I also change the type of the _ZN6myname3varE to int.And it will give the compiler error:

```
test_extern_c.cpp:15:16: error: redeclaration of ‘int _ZN6myname3varE’
 extern "C" int _ZN6myname3varE;
                ^
test_extern_c.cpp:12:9: note: previous declaration ‘int myname::var’
     int var = 42;
```

Is something different between my environment and the book's? Or may be the different version of g++ have different rule?

I have make some explorer:

1. delete the code `extern "C" double _ZN6myname3varE;`
   and it can be compiled and the result is 42.
2. move the code `extern "C" double _ZN6myname3varE;`  to the top of namespace and change the type:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   extern "C" int _ZN6myname3varE; 

   namespace myname{
       int var = 42;
   }

   //extern double _ZN6myname3varE;

   int main(){
       printf("%d\n", _ZN6myname3varE);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

and the result is 42 also.

Comment: `_ZN6myname3varE` is a reserved identifier. I'm pretty sure your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: Highly bad stuff. If you want to extern C your code, no namespace, no class. What book?

Comment: The book's demo want to test the Name Decoration in gcc compiler.The Symbol _ZN6myname3varE is the Function Signature of the var in the namespace myname.@melpomene

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher It's a book written in Chinese.And I delete the the line of code:extern "C" double _ZN6myname3varE; And I got the result of 42.

Comment: Well, throw away the book :/

Comment: Double looks wrong here: `double _ZN6myname3varE;`, but I think we need more context, like what the book actually said. Maybe the book is trying to place `int var` in the global namespace, and `double var` in the `myname` namespace to show they don't collide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that *name mangling* is an implement-specific feature and is not defined by the C++ standard. So, not all C++ compilers would generate the same *mangled* name for the same declaration.

However, GNU compiler uses the [IA64 ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling) specification for name mangling. In that sense, your example, `_ZN6myname3varE`, is a mangled representation of `myname::var`, but the type is determined from the declaration, i.e., `int` for the former declaration of `myname::var`. And the compiler sees the latter as a re-declaration of the same name, which is prohibited.

Comment: It's not a redeclaration, it's an extern, a forward declaration. Perfectly fine to to forward declarations.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher `extern "C"` highly differs from simply `extern`. You can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1041880/4614306) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace myname{
        extern int var;
}

extern "C" int _ZN6myname3varE = 42;

int main(){
        printf("%d\n", _ZN6myname3varE);
            return 0;
}
```

although there's still a complaint about using extern and initializng

Comment: I try this but an error is still happen.It means the redeclaration of the 'int _ZN6myname3varE'. The symbol _ZN6myname3varE is the Name Decoration of var in the namespace, so it's a redeclaration.Also ,I use the gcc compiler, other compiler may work.

Answer (score 0):

change double to int, it can work.

```
[root@centos-test tmp]# cat t.cc
#include <stdio.h>

namespace myname{
    int var = 42;
}

extern "C" int _ZN6myname3varE;

int main(){
    printf("%d\n", _ZN6myname3varE);
    return 0;
}
[root@centos-test tmp]# ./t
42
[root@centos-test tmp]#
```

Comment: What cpmpiler do you use?GCC?I try ths in my computer use gcc, and an error happen.error: redeclaration of ‘int _ZN6myname3varE’.IThe reason maybe the symbol of var is _ZN6myname3varE　in the gcc standard.

Comment: @windyear  g++ 4.8.5